# Group by Every id and get First date

Tags: python, django, postgresql, orm

Somebody help me,
I have data like this using postgresqlq :

id|Orderid |Note |Date
................................................
1 |1          |Tes1  | 2018-12-11
2 |1          |Tes1  | 2018-12-12
5 |2          |Tes1  | 2018-12-09
6 |2          |Tes1  | 2018-12-07

i want group orderid and get first date in every orderid,result like this :

id|Orderid |Note |Date
................................................
1 |1          |Tes1  | 2018-12-11
6 |2          |Tes1  | 2018-12-07

How to make orm in django ?

Comment: if you want group by`Orderid`. why results you have 2 item same `Orderid` ?

Comment: I have edited, different orderid

Answer (score 0):

```
SomeModel.objects.values('Orderid').annotate(Min('Date'))
```